# CSS hover image max-width: 100% not working

Tags: image, background, hover, css

I've got two big css image hovers... and I want the images to be max-width:100% (for phones). I can make the divs max-width 100% but then the image inside them just logically gets cut off by the div edge. How can I make sure that the image (in this case a background-image) in the div also does the 100% max-width?

Demo: http://www.buzz-creative.nl/_test/index.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: div { width: 100%; } img { width: 100%; } should work, or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, i'm not using an image, but a background image. Maybe i could turn it around and use img hover instead of a backgroundimage hover, but i don't really know how...

Comment: you can make an image fill a div with css

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZuX4p/

This uses background-size: 100% to make the background image fill the div, the only problem with this is you have to specify height and width, as there is no content in the div so it wants to be 0px by 0px

Answer (score 0):

try, `background-size:auto;`

link http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: abhinav, that doesn't seem to do the trick. Somehow it's nog adjusting to the div when it gets smaller... it's still staying the 448px width that i specified for the div.

Comment: uhhh? i need to specify a width for the div for when the two divs fit next to eachother right? But they're not both 50%... What value do i give the min-width then? Cause want it to get smaller when watching the site on phone.

Comment: I can fix it just using a javascript hover instead of a css hover, but i thought this might be better... but since i can't get it to work, i think it's back to javascript.

Comment: yes, get the screen width and height using javascript and make the background-size property relative to that.